# How to get the percentage of count under filtered selection of records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Having a schema (**Perf_Stat**) that is getting populated with performance stats over a period of time as:

```
Event              Event_Ts         Event_Stat
------------------------------------------
Entry        2021-02-15 19:30:10       Success
Update       2021-02-15 19:35:10       Success
Delete       2021-02-15 19:23:10       Failure
Update       2021-02-15 19:68:10       Success
Delete       2021-02-15 18:30:10       Failure
Update       2021-02-15 18:59:10       Success
and so no.....
```

I need to get the count in the percentage of failed **Update** events from this table for every last one hour whenever executed. Like

on its next run, it should give me the result as:

```
**23%** (Which denotes 23% of the total **Update** events that failed in the last hour)
```

What I tried and failing is :

```
SELECT COUNT
(
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Perf_Stat WHERE Event = 'Update' AND DATEDIFF(hour, Event_Ts, GETDATE() < 1) AND Event_Stat = 'Failure') * 100
    ) / 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Perf_Stat WHERE Event = 'Update' AND DATEDIFF(hour, Event_Ts, GETDATE() < 1)
    )
) from Perf_Stat;
```

but, I am getting aggregate function errors. Please suggest how to get the desired result.

Comment: Do you need just the last hour or do you want to aggregate it over the whole table by the hour? And is the start and end of an hour at o'clock: 1:00, 2:00, or is it exactly an hour ago say 1:07, 2:07

Comment: It's the exact last one hour.

Comment: Then Gordon's second answer will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the count in the percentage of failed Update events from this table for every last one hour whenever executed.

I would approach this as:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Event = 'Update' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM FROM Perf_Stat
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, Event_Ts, GETDATE()) < 1;
```

I assume that the time comparison is what you really want -- the last full hour.  For the last hour, I would use:

```
WHERE Event_Ts >= DATEADD(hour, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I need the count to be displayed in percentage terms, will AVG() does that?

Comment: @Aashu... Yes It will so long as you use `1.0` and not `1`

Comment: @Aashu... . . . This produces the value as a number between 0 and 1 -- a ratio.  You can use `100.0` instead of `1.0` to get a value between 0 and 100.